# In LyX, what is the most standard way to type a system of equations?

Tags: equations, lyx, amsmath

I have a system of equations and would like the alignment to be done on the equal sign.

```
 phi_{t+1}  =  F\xi_{t}  
 y_t        =  A'X_t
 \theta_t   = \mu + \epsilon_t
```

What is the most standard way to have this with LyX ? Do I need to install additional packages ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert → Math → Ams Align Environment

and then in the left part `y_t` and the right `= A'X_t`, then hit `ctrl-enter` to get a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved procedure in case you need a system of equations properly aligned on the equal sign, and with a left curly bracket:

[image]

It consists in using an `AlignedAt` environment within separators.

- Don't use the `Cases` environment which provides bracket, multiple rows and columns at once. The alignment would be incorrect for the left column and the spacing would be too large between columns.
- Prefer `AlignedAt` over `Align`. The former creates columns with no additional space between right/left pairs, contrary to the latter. See [Difference between align and alignat environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200813/289991).

The detailed procedure follows.

---

**Resizing left bracket**

- Menu `Insert | Math | Delimiters`, then unselect `Keep matched` and select a curly bracket for the left delimiter, and `None` for the right delimiter. Click the `Insert` button:

  [image]

  Close the dialog. You have got a left bracket and an input box. This box can now be populated by an `AlignedAt` environment.

**Columns**

- Menu `Insert | Math | AMS AlignedAt Environment`. This gives you a row of two columns. Enter your first equation.

**Rows**

- Add as many rows as you need using `Ctrl-Enter`. Be sure the cursor is at the end of the first row, and the status bar displays `align AlignedAt` and not `align`. Else you will add rows, but not inside the `AlignedAt` environment:

  [image]