# Difference between align and alignat environments

Tags: amsmath

What is the difference between align and alignat environments?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The first difference we find is in the syntax for calling the two environments:

```
\begin{align}
```

doesn't want an additional argument, while

```
\begin{alignat}{<number>}
```

requires it. Both environments create alignments based on *pairs of* `rl` *columns*; `align` will create as many as desired based on the environment's contents, while `alignat` requires you to specify how many pairs you want in advance.

However, the two environments differ much more than described above. The `align` environment will add horizontal space between the column pairs

```
<r col><l col> <space> <r col><l col> <space> <...>
```

while `alignat` will insert *no* horizontal space. For an instance, see [Align-environment: Align on the left side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200502/align-environment-align-on-the-left-side), where an alignment of type

```
<l col><l col>
```

is desired, which is obtained by using empty right aligned columns:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
&ABC  &&= ABC - AB\\
&ABCD &&= ABC - ABCDEFG
\end{alignat}
```

Both environments have an implicit `{}` at the beginning of cells in the left aligned columns, to help getting good spacing when a cell starts with a relation or operation symbol.

Other uses of `alignat` are when we want finer control on the horizontal spacing between (pairs of) columns. Such spacing should be specified explicitly such as in

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& m   \quad && \text{módulo}            \quad && m>0\\
& a   \quad && \text{multiplicador}     \quad && 0<a<m\\
& c   \quad && \text{constante aditiva} \quad && 0\leq c<m\\
& x_0 \quad && \text{valor inicial}     \quad && 0\leq x_0 <m
\end{alignat*}
```

(see [Aligning equations with text with alignat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat)). Such a control is not possible with `align`, because it adds the same horizontal space between all column pairs.

Both environments have the `*` form and accept `\tag` or `\notag` in any row.

There are also the “inner” versions `aligned` and `alignedat`, that obey the same rules, for use inside math mode (inline formulas, displayed formulas, math alignments).

Comment: small quibble with your last sentence ... "inside other alignments" is a bit narrower than it needs to be.  these "inner" versions should work within *any* display environment, and in fact i've seen both used within in-line `$...$` following `\item` in a list; see [Enumerate formulas](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98399/579).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the worthy (as always) remark.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Isn't the last paragraph what you were asking for?

Comment: @egreg Does an equation inside the alignedat environment break between pages?

Comment: @QGravity `alignat` honors `\displaybreak`. But `alignedat` makes an unbreakable unit.