# What is the actual function of "&" in math environment?

Tags: math-mode, syntax

First of all, I must and want to say that I really like the idea of this website. It's pretty awesome to have a place like this where you can ask all your questions regarding LaTeX/TeX. :D

My question might be rather trivial.
In fact, I have not really figured out the actual function of the `&` sign in mathematical environments.
I know that one can use it in order to add explanations of variables next to mathematical formulas.
If I add e.g. the expression `&& i &= \text{interest}` under a formula that contains the variable `i`, I can define that as the interest rate in the specific formula and in the final document it will appear next to the formula.

But what does the `&` exactly do? Why do I have to add two of it in order to have a correct typesetting.
As you might have already noticed, I haven't understood the syntax of it yet. :D

It would be so nice if somebody could help me with this one.

Thank you very, very much in advance.

Best regards,

Marcel

---

OK, so I want to provide the code I promised yesterday.

The original code I referred to yesterday is this one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
G(x) &= 0 & G &= \text{Gewinn} \\
&& x &= \text{Menge} \\
\Leftrightarrow E - K = 0 \\
&& E &= \text{Erlös} \\
&& K &= \text{Kosten} \\
\Leftrightarrow E = K \\
\Leftrightarrow p \cdot x = K_{f} + k_{v} \cdot x \\
&& p &= \text{Preis} \\
&& K_{f} &= \text{Fixkosten} \\
&& k_{v} &= \text{variable Kosten}\\
\Rightarrow x = \frac{K_{f}}{p - k_{v}}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Code 1]

I simply copy-pasted the structure from another forum and used it to express my own formulas, but did not really understand what it does - until yesterday. :)
With the explanations of `&` as an alignment marker I got yesterday, I managed to align the formulas at the arrow signs:

```
[\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
G(x) &= 0 & G &= \text{Gewinn} \\
&& x &= \text{Menge} \\
&\Leftrightarrow E - K = 0 \\
&& E &= \text{Erlös} \\
&& K &= \text{Kosten} \\
&\Leftrightarrow E = K \\
&\Leftrightarrow p \cdot x = K_{f} + k_{v} \cdot x \\
&& p &= \text{Preis} \\
&& K_{f} &= \text{Fixkosten} \\
&& k_{v} &= \text{variable Kosten}\\
&\Rightarrow x = \frac{K_{f}}{p - k_{v}}\\
&bzw.\ \boxed{p = \frac{K_{f}}{x} + k_{v}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}]
```

[image: Code 2]

That looks much tidier. So I think that I understood the basic functionality of `&`.
But what I'm still uncertain about is the meaning of `&&`.
I also experimented a bit with that and it appears to me that this is just meant to create space. Similar to using the tab button in programs like Word.
Did I get that right?

Thanks again. :D

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) the `&` is used as an alignment marker among groups of equations or other math notation (e.g. matrix columns) treated together within a single environment.  since the rules are somewhat different for different packages and environments, it's best to consult the package documentation for specifics.

Comment: As an example if you load `amsmath` package and type `\begin{align}123456789 &= x\\y = 123456789\end{align}` then they will be aligned at the `=` sign instead of just centered. But every package uses it for different alignment purpose. If you include your own code then more suitable answer can be given.

Comment: Hi! @barbara explained it well. For `align`, we surely have a nicely written answer explaining the behaviour, for instance this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200813/difference-between-align-and-alignat-environments/200844#200844

Answer (score 5):

In TeX `&` is used for alignment. That is, aligning parts of equations on different lines. My favourite example is the `cases` environment and, as egreg says in the comments, other common examples include matrices, via `array`, tables, via `tabular` ,and the many 
[amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) alignment environments like `align`, `split` ...

If you want an ampersand in mathematics use `\&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ |x| = \begin{cases}
             x, &\text{if }x\ge0,\\
            -x, &\text{if }x<0.
         \end{cases}
\]

For an ampersand in math-mode type $\&$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other examples include matrices and the `align` environment.

Comment: back to the documentation -- `gather` is *not* an aligned environment.  an unwary `&` in that environment will not do anything useful, and may even result in an error message for a `misplaced &`.