# Align, the second & does not align "right"

Tags: align

The following code:

```
            \begin{align*}
                2(3-x) \leq 2 &\Leftrightarrow 6-2x &\leq 2 \\ 
                              & \Leftrightarrow -2x &\leq 2-6  
            \end{align*}
```

looks like this

[image]

does not align \leq, how one can align in this example the \leq signs? 
Thnak you!

Comment: the `&` in `align` treat the intervening material in pairs, with each pair being handled as an independent equation, "centered" on the sign of relation.  so to get the  right-hand expressions to line up "to the left", insert two `&` before them.  (i'll look for a duplicate; i know this has been answered before.)  welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, as you say, above question is probably duplicate, but anyway,  help to beginner on SE list and convert your comment to answer.

Comment: the answer to this question explains the alignment protocol when multiple elements appear on a single line of an aligned display: [Difference between align and alignat environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844/579).

Comment: @Zarko -- done.  (i wanted to steal some of the text from the answer i knew existed; it's described much better than what i wrote in the first comment.)

Answer (score 2):

the `align` environment is based on pairs of `rl` columns; it will create as many as desired based on the environment's contents, and add horizontal space between the column pairs:

```
<r col><l col> <space> <r col><l col> <space> <...>
```

the segments on a line are separated by `&`, so if a column is omitted, the `&` must still be present to keep the proper alignment for the remaining columns.