# Is there an environment similar to alignat, but embedded in a single equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, alignat

As explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844/23166), the difference between `align` and `alignat` lies chiefly in the presence of some spacing between even and odd columns.

I would like to get the same result as with `alignat` (i.e. no spacing) but with a unique equation tag, similar to the use of `aligned` within `equation` (which adds spacing in the same way as `align`)

### mwe

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
I would like the same spacing as in:
    \begin{alignat}{2}
      \nu_n &= \mu_n \vec{F}_n &&= - \mu_n \nabla\phi_n\\
      \nu_p &= \mu_p \vec{F}_p &&= - \mu_p \nabla\phi_p,
    \end{alignat}
but with only one tag, as in:
    \begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
        \nu_n &= \mu_n \vec{F}_n &&= - \mu_n \nabla\phi_n\\
        \nu_p &= \mu_p \vec{F}_p &&= - \mu_p \nabla\phi_p
      \end{aligned}.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: you might try taking a look at the `amsmath` user's guide (`texdoc amsmath`).  it covers all the possibilities in very few pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the "internal" form `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  \nu_n &= \mu_n \vec{F}_n &&= - \mu_n \nabla\phi_n\\
  \nu_p &= \mu_p \vec{F}_p &&= - \mu_p \nabla\phi_p,
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You may want to add a small negative space `\!` in front of the `alignedat` environment, see [e.g. here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98482/).

Comment: wow i was looking for an `alignedat` environment exactly.... but when i tried something was wrong in my code (errors showed up), so i thought that ther was no `alignedat` ended up googling.. but nothing showed up for `alignedat`!

Answer (score 0):

a partial solution may be to use subequations:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}\label{both:equations}
      \begin{alignat}{2}
        \nu_n &= \mu_n \vec{F}_n &&= - \mu_n \nabla\phi_n\\
        \nu_p &= \mu_p \vec{F}_p &&= - \mu_p \nabla\phi_p,
      \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

which allows to reference both equations with one number - but still produces two tags...