# Error message when using split within alignat

Tags: alignat, split

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\newcommand{\prodsincos}{\prod_{j\in A}
\sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split} \label{fn of a+b}
\cos(\alpha+\beta) & = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta \\
\sin(\alpha+\beta) & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
\end{split}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\begin{split}
\cos \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&& \sum_{|A|=2k}
\prodsincos \\
\sin \sum_j \alpha_j
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
&&\sum_{|A|=2k+1}
\prodsincos
\end{split}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

The code above works fine if I omit `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`.  The purpose of `split` was to get just one equation number.  With `split`, I get this error message:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate
```

What should I do?

Comment: Split only allows for a single alignment column, thus only one &  per row. You're probably looking for alignedat

Comment: this is a good example of why `equation` should be used for "one-line" (or one equation number) displays rather that `align` and friends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have just one equation number it is reasonable to use `equation` as the outer environment.  A `split` will provide a single alignment point, if you need more use `alignedat`, or `aligned`, instead.  For the differences between `aligned` and `alignedat`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844/15925; most notable is the default amount of spacing added by `aligned`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[M#1]{$\scriptstyle#2$}}

\newcommand{\prodsincos}{\prod_{j\in A}
\sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split} \label{fn of a+b}
    \cos(\alpha+\beta) & = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta \\
    \sin(\alpha+\beta) & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned} \label{fn2 of a+b}
    \cos(\alpha+\beta) & = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta \\
    \sin(\alpha+\beta) & = \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    \cos \sum_j \alpha_j
    & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
    && \sum_{\eqmathbox{|A|=2k}}
    \prodsincos \\
    \sin \sum_j \alpha_j
    & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k
    &&\sum_{\eqmathbox{|A|=2k+1}}
    \prodsincos
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    z &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}&&\text{by Pythagoras}\\
    &= 5&&\text{inserting \( x=3 \), \( y=4 \)}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: both `aligned` and `alignedat` supports more than one alignment column, `split` only supports one.

Comment: @daleif Yes, I always forget that, but it is not mentioned in the AMS documentation.  For other people reading this see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844/15925. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aligned`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\prodsincos}{\prod_{j\in A}\sin\alpha_j \prod_{j\notin A} \cos\alpha_j}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{fn of a+b}
  \begin{aligned}
    \cos(\alpha+\beta) &= \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
    \sin(\alpha+\beta) &= \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \cos \sum_j \alpha_j
    &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \sum_{|A|=2k} \prodsincos\\
    \sin \sum_j \alpha_j
    &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \sum_{|A|=2k+1} \prodsincos
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first: yes, but in the second OP wants additional horizontal aligning.