# Vertical alignment with multiple columns in math mode

Tags: vertical-alignment

How do I get the $v$ to align correctly with the $dv$ above it

```
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  u &= \ln\left(x^4-1\right)   && \qquad && \dif v &= \dif x \\
  \dif u &= \frac{4x^3}{x^4-1} && \qquad && v &= x
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly what you want, you should replace the `&&` before the `\qquad` by a single `&&` and remove the other double `&&`.  this answer may help you understand how this works: [Difference between `align` and `alignat` environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Worked. TY.

Comment: would it be fair to close this as a duplicate of the cited question/answer?

Comment: Well, it's not an exact duplicate and I did read that before posting and couldn't quite figure it out. It's good to have a specific example that does what you want. OTOH, I'm not overly familiar with tex.SE's policies and that question has a link to another question which gives good examples.