# Align different equations on different equal signs

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I am using the \begin{align*} command to structure equations such that they align along the first equal sign. I want to be able to change from one equal sign to another, such that I centre equations a to w on the first equal sign, and then centre the z equation on the second equal sign. Attached is the output I'm getting. Any pointers?

```
\begin{align*}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f+g+h+j=w\\
x&=y\\
z&=0\\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

I would like to be able to align the first three equations on the first equal sign and the last two equations on the second equal sign like so:

```
a=b
c=d
e=f+g+h+j=w
        x=y
        z=0
```

Comment: take a look at what can be done with `alignedat`.  something useful might be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200813/579

Answer (score 15):

Two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
a &= b\\
c &= d\\
e &= f+g+h &{}+j &= w \\
  &        &   x &= y\\
  &        &   z &= 0
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d\\
e &= f+g+h\begin{aligned}[t]{}+j &= w \\
                               x &= y\\
                               z &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `{}` in front of `+` is needed to get the spacing right, because TeX doesn't consider `+` a unary symbol.

[image]

Comment: Umm, that `{}` in the second example gives more space than actually required.

Comment: @AboAmmar Really?

Comment: Yes, the first one is exact but the second has more space between `h` and `+`. To make sure, add a third line `e &= f+g+h+j=w \\%` and compare.

Comment: @AboAmmar Not in my output. If *you* get more space, it's time to update your TeX distribution. Quite recently, `amsmath` has been updated not to add `\,` in this situation. Ensure to have version 2.16a, released 2016/11/05.

Comment: ,@egreg -- You are right, mine is `amsmath.sty    2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features`. Does `MiKTeX` lag a bit?

Comment: @AboAmmar Sorry, I can't run MiKTeX. And don't want to. ;-)

Comment: @egreg excellent update to `amsmath` do you know where it came from?

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

> [image]

Using two nested `aligned` environments; the outer `aligned` deals with the first three `=`s and the inner one deals with the last three `=`s. The negative space of `\!` is a correction.

**Edit**

Thanks to @egreg, this negative space `\!` is no longer needed as long as you have the latest version of `amsmath` installed (version 2.16a, released 2016/11/05).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
  a &= b\\
  c &= d\\
  e &= \!\begin{aligned}[t]f+g+h+j
            &= w\\
            x&=y\\
            z&=0
        \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
ths
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f+g+h+j&&=w\\
&        &x&=y\\
&        &z&=0\\
\end{alignat*}

or to get rid of the space
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a&=b\\
c&=d\\
e&=f+g+h+j&&=w\\
&        &\llap{$x$}&=y\\
&        &\llap{$z$}&=0\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `aligned` and a horizontal correction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a&=b\\
  c&=d\\
  e & =f+g+h+\mspace{-\medmuskip}\begin{aligned}[t] j & =w \\
  x&=y\\
  z&=0
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as noted in discussion under egreg's answer the negative space is only needed for older amsmath installations not a current one.

Comment: @David Carlisle: my version is 2.16a, and I observed a difference of 0.7 pt between the spacings of `+ g` and  of `+ j`.