# Empty space in a aligned environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am attempting to align some equations using a `align` environment.
However it seems that when I try to make empty cells it fails to align properly

How do I properly have a empty cell in a `align` environment?

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &\cdot(1,c)&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &= (a+b,c)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `split` only allows one alignment point.  Perhaps you need some form of `aligned`.

Comment: As Steven guessed you need aligned not split, if you want more that one alignment. Btw you probably need more &'s. Split only handles one single alignment. Nowadays I tend to use aligned as the goto inner env instead of split.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for that.  It seems that `aligned` still has a problem, albeit not a compilation error, so I have changed the question.

Comment: @MöbiusStripMall -- you might benefit from looking at this question: [Difference between `align` and `alignat` environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200844)

Answer (score 4):

While not wholly clear what you seek, this may be it, here using TABstacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setstackaligngap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\alignCenterstack{
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &&= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &\cdot(1,c)&&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &&= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &&= (a+b,c)
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, with a `\tabularCenterstack` instead of an `\alignCenterstack`, to produce the identical output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &\cdot(1,c)&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &= (a+b,c)
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution with `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{r@{}cl}
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &{}\cdot{}(1,c)&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &= (a+b,c)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the spacing around the `\cdot`.

Comment: ups, corrected!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
aligned
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &&= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &\cdot(1,c)&&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &&= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &&= (a+b,c)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}


alignat
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(a,1)+(b,1)                     &          &&= (a+b,1) \\
((a,1)+(b,1))                   &\cdot(1,c)&&= (a+b,1)\cdot(1,c) \\
(a,1)\cdot(1,c)+(b,1)\cdot(1,c) &          &&= (a+b,c) \\
(a,c)+(b,c)                     &          &&= (a+b,c)
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```