# How the `\alignat` works in ams package

Tags: amsmath, alignat

I have read the related question([Difference between align and alignat environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200813/132752)), which had detailed answer but still don't know what the meaning of the `\alignat`'s argument. It is said in http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~ivan/math/amsldoc.pdf that

> This environment takes one argument, the number of “equation
>   columns”: count the maximum number of `&`s in any row, add 1 and and
>   divide by 2.

What is the meaning of adding one in `&` number and divide by two? I presumed the argument is given by the user, not automatically generated by the system?

Comment: `\begin{alignat}{3}` means you want three pairs of “right-left columns”. Hence you need five `&` as separator between the total six columns.

Comment: @Rikeijin: Another way to explain (which I find more illuminating) is that every column of alignments, except the first, has to be introduced by an `&`, and thaat inside each column the alignment point has to be specified by another `&`. For n columns, this makes 2n – 1 `&`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've always found the description of `alignat` based on the number of `&` tokens confusing. It's simpler than that: first you decide how many parts your alignment consists of, then adjust the number of `&` tokens.

Both `align` and `alignat` build tables consisting of pairs of a right aligned column and a left aligned column.

The argument to `\begin{alignat}` tells how many pairs you want. So, for instance, `\begin{alignat}{3}` sets things up for a total of six columns (three pairs); therefore the number of `&` in each line is five.

Answer (score 6):

`alignat` can also align a single equation, if needed. That is,

```
\begin{alignat}{1}
  f(x) &= a x^2 + b x + c
\end{alignat}
```

would yield the same output as

```
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= a x^2 + b x + c
\end{align}
```

However, in the above snippet, there is only *one* `&`. Any subsequent alignment (or equation column) will require *two* `&`s, the first to allow for a right alignment and the second for a left alignment.

So, in general, the number of `&` + 1 (to double up for the first/left-most alignment) divided by 2 will be equivalent to the number of equation columns.

Comment: I cannot choose both reply as accepted answer but both are great answer!

Comment: @Rikeijin: Once you have the [privilege to vote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you can vote to show support. It's different from accepting an answer.