# How to Align Equation Exactly in Multiple Places

Tags: align

I want to align the below equations at the start and at each equal sign. I have already looked at some previous questions and used their suggestions. However when I tried it in the below code, the some of the equal signs are not exactly aligned with each other. I have no idea why that is the case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    &\sin \theta &= \sin (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= -\sin (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &= - \sin (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
    &\cos \theta &= -\cos (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= -\cos (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &=  \cos (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
    &\tan \theta &= -\tan (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= \tan (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &=  -\tan (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [How the `alignat` works in AMS package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411024/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You possibly want a more symmetric alignment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pl}[1]{(#1^{\circ}-\theta)}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
% R          L     R              L    R               L    R
\sin \theta &={} & \sin \pl{180} &={} &-\sin \pl{270} &={} &-\sin \pl{360} \\
\cos \theta &={} &-\cos \pl{180} &={} &-\cos \pl{270} &={} & \cos \pl{360} \\
\tan \theta &={} &-\tan \pl{180} &={} & \tan \pl{270} &={} &-\tan \pl{360}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

The `={}` bits are to coerce TeX into adding the right space after the relation symbol. I added markers for remembering the column alignment (pairs of Right and Left aligned columns).

The `\pl` macro avoids clumsy and error prone input.

[image]

Here's the complete table, with the error fixed (the tangent of theta is the cotangent of 270 minus theta).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pl}[1]{(#1^{\circ}-\theta)}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
% R          L     R              L    R               L    R             L      R
\sin \theta &={} & \cos\pl{90} &={} & \sin \pl{180} &={} &-\sin \pl{270} &={} &-\sin \pl{360} \\
\cos \theta &={} & \sin\pl{90} &={} &-\cos \pl{180} &={} &-\cos \pl{270} &={} & \cos \pl{360} \\
\tan \theta &={} & \cot\pl{90} &={} &-\tan \pl{180} &={} & \cot \pl{270} &={} &-\tan \pl{360}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Very good for your wonderful works. +1

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `alignat` environment then the entries will be aligned alternately to the right and to the left:
  right-left-right-left -...
(because we are constructing several equations of type a = b c = d ...)

In your code, the initial `&` of each line produces an unwanted effect (aligns to the left!). So you have to delete it. And, additionally, from the second `=`, you will have to correct the alignment with a double `&`.

However, it is probably more aesthetic to align also the functions, so in the negative entries it will be better to write `&=-&` (instead of `&&-`).

Here you have the two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    \sin \theta &= \sin (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &&= -\sin (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &&= - \sin (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
    \cos \theta &= -\cos (180 ^{\circ}-\theta )&&= -\cos (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &&=  \cos (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
    \tan \theta &= -\tan (180 ^{\circ}-\theta )&&= \tan (270 ^{\circ} + \theta)  &&=  -\tan (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   \sin \theta &= &\sin (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= -&\sin (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &= - &\sin (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
   \cos \theta &= -&\cos (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= -&\cos (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &=  &\cos (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)\\
   \tan \theta &= -&\tan (180 ^{\circ}-\theta ) &= &\tan (270 ^{\circ} + \theta) &=  -&\tan (360 ^{\circ} - \theta)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]