# How to write equation where all equation are in only opening curly bracket and there is no closing curly bracket and with equation number

Tags: equations, empheq

[image]

How to write equation where all equation are in only opening curly bracket and there is no closing curly bracket and with equation number

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: This looks a lot like a `cases` environment (amsmath package).

Comment: [Mico's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687738/119) below is how I would do it, but your displayed example shows that the terms on the left of the equals sign to be left aligned. If you use `aligned` you will get a result having them right alighted. If that's an issue, you will want to look at the [`alignedat`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200813/difference-between-align-and-alignat-environments) environment.

Comment: I would consider [to put the brace on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIutA.png). That makes more sense when it comes to the numbering, if on the right side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you embed a

```
\left\{ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned} \right.
```

construct in an ordinary `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a &= b+c \\
d &= e+f \\
g &= h+i \\
j &= k+l
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```